# Connecting an Azure Devops Server instance to AD

Tags: azure-devops-server, tfs-2017

Sorry for the noob question - I'm a developer and don't know much about Windows administration. I'm upgrading from TFS 2017 to Azure Devops Server (onPrem). This will be on a new set of boxes though so it's not an in-plaee upgrade. Right now I'm doing proof-of-concept testing on a machine not on our domain so obviously I can't add users from the domain. My question is once I install Azure Devops Server on a machine on the domain will it automatically sync with the corporate domain? I've read that that happens once an hour - I'm just wondering if there's anything I need to install/setup to make that happen.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "sync with the corporate domain?"  What behaviors or changes would you expect to see each time this happens?

Comment: I mean when you click on Add User and start typing a user name it knows that user exists (either by auto-completing the name or ultimately by allowing the user (domain\user) to be added.)

Comment: Are you using Azure Active Directory?

Comment: No. (At least not as I understand it). I think AAD is a cloud-based version of Windows AD and everything here is on-premises.

Answer (score 0):

What you need is to **join the Windows server** which installs Azure DevOps Server **to Active Directory**.

After that it will automatically sync with the corporate domain.
However, Azure DevOps use a background synchronization job, scheduled every hour, to look for changes in Active Directory (or the local machine workgroup if the server is not domain joined). So changes you make to local or Active Directory groups do not get reflected in Azure DevOps immediately. Instead, Azure DevOps will synchronize those groups regularly (by default every hour).

That's all required. After this, you could directly add domain users or groups to groups in Azure DevOps server.

You can also try to **force Azure DevOps Server to sync with Active Directory** by following instructions mentioned in this article: [How to synchronize TFS users with AD (Active Directory)?](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/24305.how-to-synchronize-tfs-users-with-ad-active-directory.aspx), it's still available for current Azure DevOps Server versions.

Comment: @Ben_G May I know if you have resolved the issue by following the instructions?